# Load Files From Server To Dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a bootstrap modal with a dropzone form inside of it.  I'm wanting to load a list of images from the server on modal.show() and give the user the ability to remove or add images from dropzone.  I've read the wiki [here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#wiki-how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server) that shows how to insert a mock file in the init function, but that is being called before my ajax call to retrieve the list of images has returned.

If I manually type in the url to the image in the dropzone init function, it shows up fine.  Is there another way to add a file outside of the init function?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question....the magic of closures!  I knew this Secrets of the Javascript Ninjas book would come in handy!  I basically created a function inside of the Dropzone init function that returned the instance of dz and assigned it to an outer variable.  In the modal's edit button click event I call a web service to retrieve my images and the inner function returning my dz instance.  I then use that instance to load the pictures via the wiki link code.

If anyone has this same issue and wants to see code, let me know!

Comment: Hey if you still have this code, can you share it on github? I ran into a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://github.com/cognitronic/ModestoPower/blob/master/RAM.Admin.MVC/Views/Portfolio/Index.cshtml